# Sorting by description for groups of rows on a single sheet, concept inquiry

Tags: vba, excel

So, I'm a bit baffled on how to move forward, and would like some collaboration to get me started.  I'm not asking for someone to code this, but to verify my theoretical path forward.

---

**Background:**

I have a single worksheet with 30 activities.  Each activity is 75 rows, with the first of the 75 rows having a cell with the description of the activity.  Assuming the # of columns is irrelevent to this, the activities A, B, and C, would appear such as:

```
A1
A...
A75

B1
B...
B75

C1
C...
C75
```

---

**Theoretical path forward:**

Since I have a known row which starts each activity, I was thinking that I could:

.1)  Copy the known cell from each row that I intend to sort by to another sheet (this isn't preferred, but is how I can think to do it).
.2)  Once in the other sheet, Sort the activity descriptions.
.3)  Once sorted, I want to copy each of the activities 75 rows, in order, to the sorted sheet, via Match or Find.
.4)  Once completed, I would Copy the Activities from the new sheet, paste back into the original sheet, then delete the new sheet.

---

**Question:**

Does this sound appropriate?  Is there possibly a better way to do this that immediately comes to mind?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could save a lot of time copying and pasting if you used a 2 dimensional array.  This program stops at each 75th row and loads up the 2d array "Activities" from column A.  The array gets passed to bubblesort where it is sorted on the first value.  Then it is returned and all output to column B.  You might have to adjust the constants to match and if there is a blank row between activities there will be some other minor adjustments to the two main loops.

```
Option Compare Text

Const RowsPerActivity As Integer = 75 'setting
Const NumActivities As Integer = 30 'setting
Const RowtoSortOn As Integer = 1 'setting

Sub SortGroups()

Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Set MySheet = Worksheets("sheet1")

Dim Activities(1 To NumActivities, 1 To RowsPerActivity) As Variant
Dim CurActivity, CurDataRow As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer

LastRow = MySheet.Cells(MySheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For CurActivity = 1 To LastRow Step RowsPerActivity 'maybe +1 if there is a blank row between activities
  For CurDataRow = 1 To RowsPerActivity Step 1
    Activities((CurActivity \ 75) + 1, CurDataRow) = MySheet.Cells(CurActivity + CurDataRow - 1, 1).Value
  Next CurDataRow
Next CurActivity

Call BubbleSort(Activities)

For CurActivity = 1 To LastRow Step RowsPerActivity 'maybe +1 if there is a blank row between activities
  For CurDataRow = 1 To RowsPerActivity Step 1
    MySheet.Cells(CurActivity + CurDataRow - 1, 2).Value = Activities((CurActivity \ 75) + 1, CurDataRow)
  Next CurDataRow
Next CurActivity

End Sub

Sub BubbleSort(ByRef list() As Variant)
'   Sorts an array using bubble sort algorithm
    Dim First As Integer, Last As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim Temp As Variant

    First = LBound(list, 1)
    Last = UBound(list, 1)
    For i = First To Last - 1
        For j = i + 1 To Last
            If list(i, RowtoSortOn) > list(j, RowtoSortOn) Then
                For k = 1 To RowsPerActivity
                  Temp = list(j, k)
                  list(j, k) = list(i, k)
                  list(i, k) = Temp
                Next k
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for that; definitely a different way of going about the task.  I appreciate your input!  Give me some time to play around with this to see how it's working out.